# download a file and pipe it to another upload url to different API

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an image link that user can post to my app via form.

I need to download the file and make another API post request to another server.

```js
app.post('/upload', async(req, res, next) => {
  // image url is req.photo.url

  const file = await require('request-promise')(req.photo.url); // i can get the response here

  // now I need to post this file to another api
  const options = {
    method: post,
    uri: 'http://sometesturl.com/api/upload',
    body: {
      file,
    }
  };

  // but the file I am sending is not of type File and I am getting API error.
})
```

is there any way I can transform the file I downloaded into File type.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I have tried SO solutions but anything is not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: make use of [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: why don't you just pass url in post body and directly download file on the second server?

Comment: I guess you have to specify the filetype in the header, and also write the file directly to body, not as an obiect.

Comment: There is `formData` as an option in request: https://github.com/request/request-promise/blob/master/README.md (if that works depends on what the API expects)